# how to include an svg image that contains gettext in php page

Tags: php, svg, gettext

I need a PHP page to display an Inkscape-maintained svg image that contains text which upon serving is translated using `gettext` without using JavaScript and avoiding libraries.
Ideally I want a combination of:

```
<?php
    <img src="image.svg" alt="translated" />
?>
```

where the image.svg contains

```
...
<text>
   <tspan>text to be translated</tspan>
</text>
...
```

to which end I would normally use

```
<?php echo gettext("text to be translated"); ?>
```

with an accompanying .mo file that contains the translation, resulting in a php file ready for serving containing:

```
<body
    <svg>
       ....
       <text>
          <tspan><?php echo gettext("text to be translated"); ?></tspan>
      </text>
      ...
   </svg>
</body>
```

I've tried combinging many options using `include`, `file_get_contents` and `eval`, but none work smoothly, especially in cases where I have to post-edit my svg image using Inkscape or re-scan the `gettext` entries using PoEdit.

Entering php code in svg is not allowed, including svg code in php disallows Inkscape editing and `eval`'ing svg text throws out the svg, leaves just the result of the php expressions (ie. the translated text). `include`ing the svg file doesn't evaluate any php code within the svg, etc. etc.

When entering `<?php  echo gettext("text to be translated"); ?>` using the text tool in Inkscape, Inkscape will escape the whole string and generate `&lt;?php echo...` and the resulting svg file is not interpreted, even when using `eval`.

Is there an elegant way to put the above requirements together or am I using the proverbial hammer to put in a screw?

Comment: If the gettext is in the contining html page, it has no access to the image contents. The gettext would need to be in image.svg which would need toset up so that php ran on it.

Comment: @Robert Longson: What do you mean by 'set up so that php ran on it'? `eval` doesn't work here. The evaluated gettext should be (put) in the svg file. That is part of the question.

Comment: Which file contains <?php echo gettext("text to be translated"); ?>

Comment: @Robert Longson: if it were allowed: the svg file! I heared of `<foreignobject>` but am not sure if that is the proper way to go, let alone if it will yield a working solution. The final page should display the translated text in the svg file...

Comment: I've no idea what you're talking about. If **what** were allowed? foreignObject is about putting html in SVG, you seem to want the opposite of that i.e. SVG in html.

Comment: I want php, not html, in my svg file and I want it to be executable at the moment of serving too. I've modified the question to make this more clear.